# How to make one Network Interface unreachable to a process in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, ip, unmanaged

I can capture which processes are using which Network Interfaces through the help of `Managed IP Helper`. I don't know where I found it but it works as a real charm.

But do anyone know how to make entry to the table I am getting? I am finding a way so that a certain process doesn't find any way to reach the network adapter or something like that process finds that there is no network adapter available to connect to the internet.

Here is the Managed IP Helper

```
    public const string DllName = "iphlpapi.dll";
    public const int AfInet = 2;

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928.aspx"/>
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport(IpHelper.DllName, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint GetExtendedTcpTable(IntPtr tcpTable, ref int tcpTableLength, bool sort, int ipVersion, TcpTableType tcpTableType, int reserved);
```

`